# Can't get both jquery cycle and shuffle to work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle, shuffle

I am trying to get both lists to shuffle their order then cycle when the button is clicked.

http://brightboxstudios.com/test/

I am very new to jquery and javascript, so I appreciate details :)

Thanks very much for your time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to shuffle the list yourself have you tried using Cycle's random property?

```
$('.shuffle').cycle({
    fx:     'scrollDown',
    speed:  300,
    next:   '#shuffle',
    timeout: 0,
    random: 1 //Default is 0 set to 1 to randomize
});
```